# Jquery hide element by class

Tags: php, jquery

**Jquery:**

```
$("#pending").click(function()
{
    $(".pending").hide();
});
```

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<span style="font-size:2em;display:inline;position:relative;top:-30px;color:#484848;">Filter :<p id="pending" style="display:inline">Open</p><p id="wait" style="display:inline">Behandeling</p><p id="done" style="display:inline">Voltooid</p></span>
  <?php
  echo "<td>
            <div class='pending'>
             <form method='post' action='callstep.php'>
               <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$row[0]'>
               <input type='submit' value='Reply' class='small alert button'/>
             </form>
            </div>
       </td>";
   ?>
```

The above code does not work.
The `click` function works but `$(".pending").hide();` not.
(I replaced it with an `alert` to test.)

Anyone an idea ?!

Comment: A) post the rendered HTML as your PHP has nothing to do with this and 2) where's the element with the ID of pending? `$("#pending")` refers to an ID.

Comment: Can it be that it should be a id there: `$("#pending").hide();` and in that case just `$(this).hide();`?

Comment: plz do alert($('.pending').length); and let me know what it give . put it under click function.

Comment: You are hiding the element with a id which doesn't exist.

Comment: alert($('.pending').length); does not returns anything when clicking.
when simply putting it in the console and execute it, return = 413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".pending").click(function(){
    $(".pending").hide();
    });
```

There isn't any Id attribute having name `#pending`

Comment: Indeed, there is an id #pending and the click function works!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".pending").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer because the div #pending is holding the button to show / hide.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an id called "#pending" that the user is supposed to click, to make the class pending to hide.  I just don't see in your code the #pending.
Try: `<div id="pending" class="pending">`

Answer (score 0):

If the click function worked, the code looks fine to me,

Check if there is any other script making the `.pending` visible again?

Also check the css of `.pending` whether it has `display:block !important;` or something like this..

Also make sure you don't have more than one `#pending` element in your page